# How can I let users enter the cck value once and then protect the field from editing?

Tags: entities, 6, rules

I have several cck fields that shouldn't be modified once after the node is created. For example like fields for gender, name, birth date and so on.
Is it possible to hide or make them unable to edit those fields by users after the node creation?   I thought maybe I could do that by Rules but unfortunately it seems that there is no action for hiding cck field forms though it has the condition for "if field has a value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the link below will be helpful to you..

[Code snippet: How to set the disabled or readonly attribute of a CCK field](http://drupal.org/node/357328)

Check this link and let me know if in case of any query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the module, but [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) appears to create the level of permissions you are looking for, eg, it grants users permission to CREATE a CCK field value separate from the permission to EDIT it.

Comment: Thanks. But I think if I don't give users the permission to edit the fields they will not be able to enter values on node creation as well.